# class active not work with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I am since yesterday looking like fixing this error. I found several posts on the website but none worked me.
I have this code html:

```
<nav class="nav-main mega-menu">
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-main" id="mainMenu">
    <li><a href="">item1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item3</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="page-services.html">
            item4
            <i class="icon icon-angle-down"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="">item5</a></li>
            <li><a href="">item6</a></li>
            <li><a href="">item7</a></li>
            <li><a href="">item8</a></li>
            <li><a href="">item9</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">item10</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item11</a></li>
    <li><a href="">item12</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

and in the  i have this code js:

```
<script type="javascript">
   $('.nav-pills').on('click', 'li', function() {
   $('.nav-pills li.active').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
   });
</script>
```

also try this:

```
<script type="javascript">
   $('.nav-main').on('click', 'li', function() {
   $('.nav-main li.active').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
   });
</script>
```

but does not work. Can someone help me? I tried a lot of options I found on the site but this not works

Comment: Define "does not work". How should it work? What happens instead?

Comment: Try wrapping your code in a DOM ready function, so that the click event handler will be bound properly.

Comment: Your exact code: http://jsfiddle.net/pL4zgdzL/ it works - Do you see any browser console errors? Did you forget to wrap the jquery code in a dom ready handler ?

Comment: There's no reason to have both handlers; one is enough. If you put the delegated handler on `$(document)` instead of the `<ul>` or its container, you won't need to do the work in a "ready" handler.

Comment: Thanks for resnder so fast. I dont see any error in the console.
When state is in "active" the background should be blue

<code>
header nav ul.nav-main ul.dropdown-menu, header nav ul.nav-main li.dropdown.open a.dropdown-toggle, header nav ul.nav-main li.active a, header nav ul.nav-main li > a:hover, header nav ul.nav-main li.dropdown:hover a {
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #08C !important;
}
</code>

Comment: @OsquiB please don't dump code blocks in comments, [edit] your question and update it there.

Comment: and BTW I don't see any `<header>` in the above HTML to match your CSS. voting to close since the post doesn't contain enough information.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this around your code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//your code here

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this version: http://jsfiddle.net/2y2r2wmm/3/

```
$('.nav-pills').on('click', 'li', function() {
  $('.nav-pills li.active').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Can you explain the expected behaviour in more details ? The link gets the `active` class and the link text color changes to red.

Comment: When I click on item 1 this should change your color to white and background to blue.
must be shown in this way
[link](http://oi61.tinypic.com/2n8pmir.jpg)
when I add "class =" active "editing the HTML looks good but when I do with js, not work

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is not problem CSS. Your code does not work me. Indeed CSS mine works fine. If I add class = active looks good. Maybe some js file is causing problems. Thanks for your time